# What does this OpenAPI/Swagger spec mean?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

Spec in question:

```yaml
openapi: '3.0.2'
info:
  title: Video Storage Server API
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
paths:
  /files/{fileid}:
    get:
      description: Download a video file by fileid. 
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: fileid
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          headers:
            Content-Disposition:
              schema:
                type: string
          content:
            video/mp4:  # foo.mp4
              schema: 
                type: string
                format: binary
            video/mpeg: # bar.mpg 
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

I understand I need to have my server respond to a `get` request with `fileid`.
The server stores video.

The response from server, should it be like a video that user can play in browser/Postman or should be the byte array of the video?

i.e. Should the response be:

[image: Possible result 1]

or

[image: Possible result 2]

Also, what does `content#video/mp4` / `content#video/mpeg` mean? Do I need to set `content-type` in my response to be one of these 2?

What should my `Content-Disposition` be?

Comment: The keys of content are the _media types_, see e.g. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/media-types/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , thanks, so I should set my content-type to be one of these 2 keys?

Comment: _"should it be like a video that user can play in browser/Postman or should be the byte array of the video?"_ - what's the difference, exactly? Video files and other large binaries should _only_ be served over HTTP as a raw binary response (or via an appropriate application protocol like RTSP or HLS). The idea of loading a multi-gigabyte video file into a Base64 string or JSON byte array is the stuff of nightmares...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the video as in the first example, or more correctly a stream of bytes that corresponds to the requested content type, `video/mp4` or `video/mpeg`, with a `Content-Disposition` header.

If the response were to be a JSON block like in the 2nd example, the response content type would be `application/json` (or equivalent) and it would explicitly list the response object schema, ie there would be a `filename`, `fileType` and so on in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenAPI specification says:

1. Publish an endpoint /files/{fileid}, where {fileid} is a path
   parameter.
2. In the response, you provide:

- **Binary data** of the video in the message body
- **Content-Type header** with one of:

  - video/mp4
  - video/mpeg
- **Content-Disposition header** with one of values:

  - Content-Disposition: inline (if the video shall be played inside the browser)
  - Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.mp4" (if the video shall be downloaded)

See [documentation for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) about Content-Disposition header.